# Differentiate between Changed and Created events in FileSystemWatcher?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, filesystemwatcher

I'm using the `FileSystemWatcher` to monitor a certain directory, and I need to raise one event when someone saves edits to a file, and another when they create or move a file.

Monitoring moved files works fine using a combination of the `Deleted` and Created events. And when someone saves edits to a file the Changed event does indeed get raised. However, when they move a file the `Changed` event gets raised too, and that interferes with the handling I've got for the `Created` and Deleted events.

So basically, I want to raise the `Changed` event only when the user saves edits to a file, while not when the user moves or creates a file. I tried using the `ChangeType` property to check if it was in fact a `Changed` event or a `Created` event, but to my surprise, the `ChangeType` `Changed` was raised for the Change event even when moving or creating a file, not the `ChangeType` `Created` (which supposedly should be one of the types).

So I don't know how to check that the Change event is actually triggered by a file edit, rather than file creation or move...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is normal behavior when you apply some of `NotificationFilter` such as `NotifyFilter. Attributes` and `NotifyFilter.LastAccess`, it will even notify `Changed` twice if both filters was applied when file move "Deleted - Created - Changed - Changed", So:

- Simply don't add not relevant notify filters; If you just remove
  `NotifyFilter. Attributes` and `NotifyFilter.LastAccess`
  you will not receive `Changed` event when move file, only `Deleted` then `Created`.
- If you are wishes to stick with the notify filters that you are already using, there is other **hint** here to allow you to generate a *dirty* solution, it is the fact that when the file moved, the sequence of notification will be `Deleted`, `Created` then `Changed`, they will be always in this order..

Comment: Thanks, good insights. Just using the NofityFilter didn't work, because the folder raises a changed event before the files raise the deleted and created events, but I managed to fix it using a combination of your two tips and a timer. Like you said, dirty, but it works :-)